# Show normal font in a definition environment instead of italics

Tags: environments

In the code below, how do I go about having the font show up as normal font instead of the italicized font in the `commentt` environment?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\newtheorem{commenttT}{Comment}[chapter]
\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} 
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!20,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=3pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=3pt]{dBox}

\newenvironment{commentt}{\begin{dBox}\begin{commenttT}}{\end{commenttT}\end{dBox}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is how}

\begin{commentt}
\lipsum[1]
\end{commentt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\theoremstyle{definition}` before `\newtheorem`?

Comment: Off-topic: To create a color that's widely recognized as "ochre", use `\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{239,173,0}` rather than `\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0,173,239}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the user guide of the `amsthm` package:

> The amsthm package supports the notion of a current theorem style, which
>   determines what will be produced by a given `\newtheorem` command. The three
>   theorem styles provided—`plain`, `definition`, and `remark`—specify different
>   degrees of visual emphasis corresponding to their relative importance. The
>   details of this typographical treatment may vary depending on the document
>   class, but typically the `plain` style produces italic body text, while the other
>   two styles produce roman body text. These default settings are provided:
>
> • `plain` : italic text, extra space above and below;
>
> • `definition` : upright text, extra space above and below;
>
> • `remark` : upright text, no extra space above or below.
>
> If no `\theoremstyle` command is given, the style used will be `plain`.

Thus, depending on whether or not you want extra space above and below the `commenttT` environment, you should state either `\theoremstyle{definition}` or `\theoremstyle{remark}` immediately ahead of `\newtheorem{commenttT}{Comment}[chapter]`.